# Cómo comprobar si un DateTime es mayor que el otro en Flutter

Tags: flutter, condiciones, datetime

Tengo tres objetos `DateTime`: `BdP`, `BdF` y `Bt`. Quiero que en base a la hora que sea tiene que devolver uno u otro:

> Cuando sea de día:
>
> > Se devolverá un texto llamado: `Buenos días`, que va desde el rango `BdP`(que es cuando te levantas) hasta `BdF` (que es cuando comes o que la que te guste, pero siempre siendo superior a la anterior),(para ambos hay datepicker que no está puesto, pero hay que ponerlo).

> El Objeto `Bt` serviría para:
>
> > Devolver un texto llamado: `Buenas tardes`, que va desde el rango `BdF` (que es cuando comes o que la que te guste, pero siempre siendo superior a la anterior) hasta `Bt` (que es a una hora en concreto),(para el último habrá un datepicker ya que el otro se reutilizará, este último no está puesto, pero hay que ponerlo).

> El Objeto `Bn` serviría para:
>
> > Devolver un texto llamado: `Buenas noches`, que va desde el rango `Bt` hasta `BdP`(todos se reutilizarán).

[GitHub](https://github.com/0w4n/HubApp/blob/main/lib/components/time.dart#:%7E:text=%7D-,class%20Buenas3%20%7B,%7D,-%7D)

Comment: Tienes algún código para ver lo que has intentado y poder ayudarte

Comment: Si, ahora si. Se me habia olvidado.... =')

Comment: De que hora a que hora esta limitado para mostrar los mensajes? Supongo que de 08 a 12 es buenos dias?

Comment: De las 6 hasta las 15

Comment: Y las demas?Como sería la limitación?

Comment: Tarde: 15 hasta 21 y la noche desde 21 hasta las 6

Comment: El código va _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask].

Comment: El codigo va en la pregunta, porque si mañana borras ese repositorio, entonces tu pregunta deja de servirle a todos. Ademas, no hay porque mirar todo un repositorio para encontrar tu codigo y tu problema. Mira [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Hice una pantalla y dentro de esta pantalla cree un botón para poder validar la hora actual y poder hacer las condiciones para tu pregunta, espero y haya podido despejas tu duda, es un poco similar a tu ejemplo:

```
class Tiempo {
  late DateTime today = DateTime.now();
}
```

arriba de la clase donde tengo el botón declare la clase Tiempo que tu tienes en tu ejemplo, luego solo cree una instancia de esa clase en la función del botón.

```
    void validacion() {  //esta linea no agregues
     //AGREGA DESDE AQUÍ
    final time = Tiempo();
    final hour = time.today.hour;
    //Buendos días / desde
    int bdd = 6;
    //Buendos días / hasta
    int bdh = 12;

    //Buenas tardes / desde
    int btd = 12;
    //Buenas tardes / hasta
    int bth = 19;

    //Buenas noches / desde
    int bnd = 19;
    //Buenas noches / hasta
    int bnh = 00;

    if (hour >= bdd && hour < bdh) {
      return "Buenos días";
    } else if (hour >= btd && hour < bth) {
      return "Buenas tardes";
    } else if (hour >= bnd && hour < bnh) {
      return "Buenas noches";
    } else {
      return "Estamos de madrugada";
    }
  //HASTA AQUÍ
  }
```

Comment: He de decir que lo que devuelve es un texto que pongo en una parte de la app

Comment: Pero creo que lo que querías eran las validaciones, correcto? solo que hice un ejemplo dinámico para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: No tengo que utilizar un int si no un time

Comment: Acabé de editar en el ejemplo dinámico, ya implemente la clase Time, espero y eso te pueda servir, de ahí lo que tienes que hacer es retornar un texto en vez del dialogo

Comment: Y tengo un clase Buenas3 hay puedo poner la parte del void?

Comment: claro, dentro de la clase Buenas3 puedes poner el contenido del void validacion()

Comment: Como pongo para que devuelva un texto?

Comment: En tu código tu unicamente tienes un return 'buenos días', asi que supongo que lo tienes que poner tal cual. El retornarDialog('Buenos días'); reemplazalo por el return 'Buenos días.'

Comment: Me suena un poco a chino, me lo puedes explicar?

Comment: He actualizado el código

Comment: Edite nuevamente la respuesta para que veas desde donde hasta donde tienes que agregar

Comment: Vale, ¿como lo agrego al código base? ¿Al main?

Comment: Copia desde donde te dije, anda a tu código main, reemplaza las validaciones por las nuevas que puse y así mismo declara las variables int.

Comment: He actualizado el código